# Eclipse doesn't find javax.swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Eclipse cant find the `import javax.swing.JOptionPane`

Where is it located and how can i include it?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

Comment: It's included in the JDK. Post your code and the exact error message. Tell us what you have in your build path.

Comment: import statement is correct. which version of eclipse you using and what type of project you have chose while creating new project?

Comment: Is your class paths to Java proper.?

Comment: does import javax.swing.*; work?

Comment: Christian, what version of Eclipse are you using? One of those from eclipse.org? Is your project a java project? Do you have the JDK?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. There must be an installed (and selected) JDK in Eclipse:

   ```
   Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs
   ```
2. The project must be configured to use that JDK:

   ```
   Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries
   ```

   there should be an entry like "JRE System Library [JDK7]" in the list. If not press:

   ```
   Add Library... > JRE System Library
   ```
3. The project should have been created as a "Java Project":

   ```
   Project > Properties > Builders
   ```

   should include "Java Builder"

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer did not work for me.

This is how I solved it:

Right-Click on your project, select `Properties`

Go to `Java Build Path`

Click `Libraries`, then `Add Library ...`

Select `JRE System Library`

Click on `Execution environment` and select `JavaSE-1.7` or `JavaSE-1.8`

Click `Finish`, then `Apply and Close`.

Comment: This should have been an accepted solution. It worked for me too!

Answer (score 1):

Try to Update the execution environment under system library to JavaSE-1.7 or JavaSE-1.8 in eclipse.
To update the step below can be followed:

```
> Right-click on the project
> Select properties
> Java build path
> Library > Add Library > Add JRE SYSTEM Library
> Execution Environment
> Select JavaSE-1.7 or JavaSE-1.8
> Finish
```

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning when you start to create a new java project just don't click "finish" or "next" directly. But go to the JavaSE version text input at the middle of the form and choose JavaSE 1.6 or 1.7 or 1.8, then click next -> finish.
Then it with parse and work.

Answer (score 0):

and also what finally added javax library to the project is (as me have also learned from SOF) is: Project name >> right button >> Properties >> Build Path:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of my Eclipse projects couldn't find javax.swing
The other projects had no problem, the configurations were identical and default.

I found this video on Youtube[Video of changing the JRE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cm3vP06NETY)
I changed my JRE to 1.7 like suggested in video and it worked. Then, because I thought it was a bug, I changed it back to JRE 17 and it still worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).