# Why doesn't Eclipse recognize import java.JOptionPane?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm on the Eclipse program for Java developers, and for some reason, Eclipse doesn't recognize `import javax.swing.JOptionPane` when creating a new class.

If you attempt to make a new class and have the code imported automatically, nothing pops up

[image: Java Error]

In fact, nothing remotely related to `javax.swing` pops up. Any ideas on what's going on? I removed the JRE system library and re-added it again. But that didn't work.

Comment: A quick [google](https://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&dcr=0&q=eclipse+javax.swing&oq=eclipse+javax.swing&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0.0.12080.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.X2AlhOCgVQ4) brings up a few possible remedies - Have you tried any? If so, which ones didn't work for you?  In what ways is your problem "seemingly" different from the others who had similar problems?

Comment: Based on your error message, [this previous answer look promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860187/access-restriction-on-class-due-to-restriction-on-required-library-rt-jar)

Comment: You type JOptionPane in Choose a Type Textbox and then related package will show below. After that choose the below package.

Comment: @MadProgrammer That’s what I meant when I said “remove JRE library and re-add it.”

Comment: @Myo Typing javax.swing.JOptionPane should produce the same thing as typing JOptionPane. Also, simply typing JOptionPane doesn’t work either.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Replying to your first comment, I saw the question about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181142/eclipse-doesnt-find-javax-swing. I followed every step and it matches up. But JOptionPane still isn’t showing.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new fresh workspace and project to see if it occurs there? It shouldn't, of course, but I recall having instances where the metadata of a workspace or project seemed to be messed up.

Comment: @M.leRutte Yup, I just tried creating a new workspace. The same error occurs.

Comment: @Crescendo Could you add the details of 1. the jre/jdk that you're configuring. 2. `java -version` on your machine 3. eclipse version that you're using.

Comment: Also, could you state, how is this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181142/eclipse-doesnt-find-javax-swing already?

Comment: @nullpointer I fixed the problem. Kind of a dumb mistake too

Comment: @Crescendo shall this be marked as Off-Topic in that case?

Comment: Are type filters (_Window > Preferences: Java > Appearance > Type Filters_) set? If no, does rebuild the Java index (in _Window > Preferences: Java_ click the _Rebuild Index_ button) fix the problem?

Comment: @howlger I fixed it, I just uninstalled jdk and eclipse, and reinstalled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things that could be causing a problem:

1. **Make sure you have a JDK installed and selected in eclipse**

   ```
   Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs
   ```
2. **Make sure it’s in your build path**

   ```
   Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries
   ```

   One of the Libraries should be something along the lines of “JRE System Library [JDK9]”. If there isn’t one, add it with:

   ```
   Add Library > JRE System Library
   ```
3. **Your project should be a Java project**

   ```
   Project > Properties > Builders
   ```

Should have a “Java Builder” entry.

After doing all that, rebuild your project with `Project > Clean` then select your project. If none of that works, completely uninstall Java, reinstall the JDK and JRE then repeat steps 1-3. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181142/eclipse-doesnt-find-javax-swing).

Comment: I deleted Eclipse, and redownloaded it last night. It turns out that if you manually type in `import javax.swing.JOptionPane`, a red box on the right appears. But the program still runs. Is there a way to fix that part?

Comment: Hmm. Seems like an eclipse glitch. What JDK version are you using, and what eclipse version?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out what was wrong with eclipse. Not sure what, but I just uninstalled everything, reinstalled everything, and installed Eclipse into the C: folder.

Comment: Does this mean I get the bounty?