JOptionPane is not showing
I've new to java, and i'm having problem with the JOptionPane! This is my code :
package myFirstProgram;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GuiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello "+name);
        
        int age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your age"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You are "+age+" years old");
        
      
    }

}

Can someone tell me how to fix it ?

It's showInputDialog not showImputDialog

What error do you see?

It says "The package javax.swing is not accessible"

Thanks g00se, I've already corrected it but ! It's still not working !

@SatosAurel You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209125/unable-to-import-javax-swing-jframe

Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181142/eclipse-doesnt-find-javax-swing

if you are getting an error with message, that should be included in the question - almost essential to recognize what the problem is || often searching for the error message shows some links that can help
