How to fix the error "Error: could not open ......" in eclipse?
I tried reinstalling java and done with setting up path in system environment variables, but it did not work.

I tried to run the program written in java, but I'm getting this pop-up saying "Error: could not open file location"  with no result for the run.

What does your code look like?

be sure there is a valid Java installed and set up in Eclipse: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs  ||| but how is that related to Javasript? http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14182166/85421

Project Properties -> Build Path -> JRE System Libraries -> Alternate JRE -> Choose the appropriate JDK version.
Next, choose the appropriate compiler compliance level under Project Properties -> Build Path -> Java Compiler.
